# PostgreSQL errors on symfony server launch

Tags: postgresql, symfony, pdo

I am learning Symfony,
I create my project with : `symfony new myproject --full`
directly after this I run `symfony serve`

in the console I am getting thoses errors :

```
Tailing Web Server log file (/Users/ben/.symfony/log/cd52af540b09d661e4ffb4f5029da4bbaf3586a9.log)
Tailing PHP-FPM log file (/Users/ben/.symfony/log/cd52af540b09d661e4ffb4f5029da4bbaf3586a9/53fb8ec204547646acb3461995e4da5a54cc7575.log)
                                                                                                                        
 [OK] Web server listening                                                                                              
      The Web server is using PHP FPM 7.3.11                                                                            
      https://127.0.0.1:8000                                                                                            
                                                                                                                        

[Web Server ] Jun  3 23:38:48 |DEBUG  | PHP    Reloading PHP versions 
[Web Server ] Jun  3 23:38:48 |DEBUG  | PHP    Using PHP version 7.3.11 (from default version in $PATH) 
[Application] Jun  3 21:29:59 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 96 
[Application] Jun  3 21:29:59 |CRITICA| REQUES Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 96) 
[Application] Jun  3 21:29:59 |CRITICA| PHP    Uncaught Exception: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused     Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
[Application] Jun  3 21:37:59 |ERROR  | REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET https://127.0.0.1:8000/"" at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136 
[Application] Jun  3 21:38:00 |ERROR  | REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET https://127.0.0.1:8000/favicon.ico" (from "https://127.0.0.1:8000/")" at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 136 
[Application] Jun  3 21:38:00 |CRITICA| REQUES Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 96) 
[Application] Jun  3 21:38:00 |CRITICA| PHP    Uncaught Exception: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused     Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
[Application] Jun  3 21:38:00 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?" at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 96 
[Application] Jun  3 21:38:00 |CRITICA| REQUES Exception thrown when handling an exception (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused   Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? at /Users/ben/Desktop/symfonytuto/demo/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 96) 
[Application] Jun  3 21:38:00 |CRITICA| PHP    Uncaught Exception: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused     Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting     TCP/IP connections on port 5432? 
[Web Server ] Jun  3 23:38:48 |INFO   | PHP    listening path="/usr/sbin/php-fpm" php="7.3.11" port=50170
[PHP-FPM    ] Jun  3 23:38:48 |NOTICE | FPM    fpm is running, pid 1240 
[PHP-FPM    ] Jun  3 23:38:48 |NOTICE | FPM    ready to handle connections
```

After this the Symfony's default page is loading correctly but when I add a route to the url for example : `https://127.0.0.1:8000/testtt`
I'm getting this error :

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

(it should be something like 'this route doesnt exist' no ?)

Please tell me how I can give you more info about my problem !

Thanks a lot !

Comment: The Doctrine Migrations Bundle requires an actual database connection in dev mode for the profile bar.  Either remove the bundle (you can re-install later if you need it) or create a database and adjust the credentials.  By the way, what you call the 'default page' comes up when no routes are defined.  Once you define one then you will start getting these sorts of errors.

Comment: Hi @Cerad thank you for your answer,
I am following a Symfony course on Udemy.com and he didnt create any database, or removed a bundle and his error was "this route doesnt exist" or something like that.. so it's weird that I have to do something he didn't for this to work properly..

But if there is no choice can you please give me more details about your solutions (how to proceed)

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: by the way my project is not using a database yet, i litteraly just created the project and launvhed the server

Comment: Just do a 'composer remove doctrine/migrations' and the problem will go away.  You will get this error in development mode regardless of if you are using a database or not.  Just one of those things.

Comment: Hi @Cerad after running the command i got this :

doctrine/migrations is not required in your composer.json and has not been removed
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update doctrine/migrations
Loading composer repositories with package information
Dependency "composer/package-versions-deprecated" is also a root requirement. Package has not been listed as an update argument, so keeping locked at old version. Use --with-all-dependencies (-W) to include root dependencies.
Dependency "symfony/console" is also a root requirement. Package has not been

Comment: listed as an update argument, so keeping locked at old version. Use --with-all-dependencies (-W) to include root dependencies.
Dependency "symfony/stopwatch" is also a root requirement. Package has not been listed as an update argument, so keeping locked at old version. Use --with-all-dependencies (-W) to include root dependencies.
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "5.3.*"
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files

Comment: composer/package-versions-deprecated: Generating version class...
composer/package-versions-deprecated: ...done generating version class
111 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!

Run composer recipes at any time to see the status of your Symfony recipes.

Executing script cache:clear [OK]
Executing script assets:install public [OK]

Removal failed, doctrine/migrations is still present, it may be required by another package. See `composer why doctrine/migrations`.

Comment: My bad.  It is the bundle that needs removing: 'composer remove doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle'  Running the suggested composer why command would have told you that.  If you are going to be doing any sort of PHP development then you need to know the basics of composer.  And in the future, it is best to update your original question with error messages.  Comments don't format well.

Comment: @Cerad removing doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle worked but, can you explain to me why i needed to remove it and not the teacher of the course ?
Also maybe I will need it in the future ?
Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This question pops up often enough that I think an answer is appropriate until the issue is resolved.

Assume you just created a new Symfony website-skeleton app, added a new  controller and started the development server.  You navigate to your new route and exceptions are tossed.  Either get a 'driver not found' or a 'could connect to server'.  Which of course is a bit unexpected since you have not yet done anything with the database.

The problem is that the Doctrine migrations bundle provides a data collector for Symfony's profiler bar that shows up at the bottom of the browser page when running in development mode.  The data collector needs to connect to the database in order to collect migrations data.  It does not care about the fact that there is no database.  It just tries to connect and ends up tossing an exception.

I opened an [issue](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/423) on this.  I am still not entirely sure if this is a feature or  bug.  Feel free to comment on the issue if you like.

This is a fairly recent problem though I have not tracked exactly when it first popped up.  Hence many existing tutorials and step by step guides do not mention it.  Consider it to be part of your development experience.  Learning how to read exceptions is quite important.

There are several solutions.  If you plan on using a database then go ahead and **create yourself a database and adjust the DATABASE_URL** to point to it.  The database can be empty.  The migration data collector just needs to be able to connect to it.  On my local development machine I actually created a database called db_name just to avoid this error message.

A second solution is to just remove the migrations bundle with

```
composer remove doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
```

And the problem goes away.  If later on you need migrations then just use composer require to re-install it.

Comment: This should be added in the documentation "Create your First Page" or fixed quickly because it is very confusing and frustating to get this error from the first documentation exercice. Also is it just me or "driver not found" doesnt help to understand what's happening ?

Comment: A fix has actually been made.  Just has not been released yet.  The actual messages do come from deep in the heart of the database system and are reasonably accurate.  To me at least it's just a surprise to get database errors when you are not using a database.

Comment: When I run composer remove doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle it just results in "In ArrayLoader.php line 44: Unknown package has no name defined" when reloading the page. Just running through the "create your first page" tutorial and experiencing this unexpected roadblock.

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution that solves the problem without having to remove the package with `composer remove ...`.

comment out `Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],` in `/config/bundles.php`

Then move `/config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml` up one directory so it's not longer trying to be included.

This may be a little less intimidating for new developers.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue appears when you want to access the localhost.../lucky/number, go to **.env** file under the your "**folder name**" and uncomment this line:

DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"

And the rest of them with mySQl and Postgres, comment them.

Hope it works for you. :)