# disable symfony 5 database connection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

I have the default config in my symfonu project I have this line at `.env` file

```
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
```

and I get this error

```
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Of course I dont have not isntalled postgres, and I dont need a database for this project, How I cant fix this error I tried to comment the .env file line but I get another error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67829014/postgresql-errors-on-symfony-server-launch/67837958#67837958

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Commenting the line as L3xpert answer suggests doesn't seem to do the job.
It will throw the error :
*Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL".*

**If you don't need Doctrine** but you have Website-Skeleton installed, **you can remove Doctrine by running this command** :

```
composer remove doctrine/doctrine-bundle doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle
```