# Environment variable not found: "DATABASE_URL" (Symfony 5)

Tags: php, symfony

I've just started using Symfony. Firstly, I have no database in my small project. However, it forces me to use `DATABASE_URL`. So, I have to create a database. When I do this, the project works. Do I have to do this every time? I don't want use a database for small projects. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67829014/postgresql-errors-on-symfony-server-launch/67837958#67837958

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you're trying to do. Symfony is a framework made of dozens of libraries, you've given no indication what ones you're trying to use.

Comment: @miken32 There is always a tradeoff between too little and too much info in a question.  However, this sort of question gets asked every couple of days.  The question is always a bit different but the problem and the solution is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you use `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` inside your project. Just delete it `composer remove doctrine/doctrine-bundle` if you don't want to use database for your small project, then you don't need to set `DATABASE_URL`

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just resulted in other errors.

Comment: I didn't note it down but the initial line in the stacktrace mentioned ArrayLoader.php. I just set up a DB and got the "first page" tutorial working. However, I have just tried the composer command you suggested again and it worked (after also removing a mentioned dependency). The lines relating to the database were automatically removed from the .env file (which surprised me - I wanted to make a note of the connection URL). The profile debugger toolbar still works which I did not expect as I heard it depended on a DB. I suppose it is not a dependency but just uses it if a DB is present?