# How to fix "could not find driver" (at AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102) in new Symfony PHP project build following Get Started Docs?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am following the [Symfony Getting Started documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html) to build a very simple new project which consists of one page that shows you a "lucky" random number. However when I try to browse to the lucky number web page, I get an error about a missing database driver. This seems strange since I am not doing any database related activity in the new project. Where is the database driver error coming from and how can I resolve it?

**Details**

I am using a Windows 10 workstation. I have installed PHP 8, Composer, Symfony 5. I created a new project using
`symfony new test --full` as per [Setup](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html). I created a route and a controller as per [Creating Pages](https://symfony.com/doc/current/page_creation.html)

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * Description of LuckyController
 *
 * @author 
 */
class LuckyController {
    public function number(): Response
    {
        $number = random_int(0, 100);

        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

```
#index:
#    path: /
#    controller: App\Controller\DefaultController::index

app_lucky_number:
    path: /lucky/number
    controller: App\Controller\LuckyController::number
```

(Above) routes.yaml

When I start the symfony web server in my project folder `symfony server:start` and open my browser to the lucky number page http://localhost:8000/lucky/number I get an error about a missing database driver:

**[Application] Sep 20 11:37:01 |CRITICA| REQUES Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException: "An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver" at D:\Web\test\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 102**

Any ideas why I am getting a database connection error when I haven't built any database functionality with this website? All I have built is the sample page that should just show me a lucky random number.

I noticed that my .env file had an uncommented line for an example PostgreSQL database connection. In case Doctrine requires a database connection by default I updated my .env file to point to an empty local test database on mySQL:

```
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
# Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
# IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
#
# DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
# DATABASE_URL="mysql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:3306/db_name?serverVersion=5.7"
# DATABASE_URL="postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name?serverVersion=13&charset=utf8"
DATABASE_URL="mysql://test_webuser:#############@127.0.0.1:3306/test"
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

(Above) .env file (password redacted...)

However when I restart my web server and browse to the lucky number page I still get the same driver error and it is still at AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php. I'm not sure where it is getting PostgreSQL from.

I have checked over the Symfony Get Started documentation multiple times and I don't seem to have missed anything. I'm only up to the first part of creating a "hello world" type page so I'm not sure there is much to miss...

Any suggestions please as to how I can get past this error. Thanks.

**More Yaml**

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '13'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

(Above) config/packages/doctrine.yaml

```
# see https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html
framework:
    secret: '%env(APP_SECRET)%'
    #csrf_protection: true
    http_method_override: false

    # Enables session support. Note that the session will ONLY be started if you read or write from it.
    # Remove or comment this section to explicitly disable session support.
    session:
        handler_id: null
        cookie_secure: auto
        cookie_samesite: lax
        storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.native

    #esi: true
    #fragments: true
    php_errors:
        log: true

when@test:
    framework:
        test: true
        session:
            storage_factory_id: session.storage.factory.mock_file
```

(Above) config/packages/framework.yaml

```
security:
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/authenticator_manager.html
    enable_authenticator_manager: true
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#c-hashing-passwords
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        users_in_memory: { memory: null }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            provider: users_in_memory

            # activate different ways to authenticate
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#firewalls-authentication

            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/impersonating_user.html
            # switch_user: true

    # Easy way to control access for large sections of your site
    # Note: Only the *first* access control that matches will be used
    access_control:
        # - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # - { path: ^/profile, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

(Above) config/packages/security.yaml

Comment: Could you share the config/packages/doctrine.yml and also the config/packages/framework.yml and config/packages/security.yml?

Comment: @RicardoJesusRuiz I have added the yaml files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67829014/postgresql-errors-on-symfony-server-launch/67837958#67837958

Comment: Thanks @Cerad, looks like that is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

My question appears to be a duplicate of [PostgreSQL errors on symfony server launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67829014/postgresql-errors-on-symfony-server-launch/67837958#67837958)
I was able to resolve it by creating a valid database connection as per the answer to that question. (My first attempt at creating a database connection URL in this question had invalid URL characters in the password but once I resolved that the site worked and I was able to get my lucky number). I don't have enough reputation points to mark this question as a duplicate.